# Try to getting private state variables and understand the storage slots

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

This is my BasicNft contract. I deployed an nft contract. Working great. I am trying to understand storage slots. Normally what I found, The first of state variable gets the first slot. But if we have a constructor it seems to be changing.
This is my minting script:

```
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat");
const { moveBlocks } = require("../utils/move-blocks");

async function mint() {
  const basicNft = await ethers.getContract("BasicNft");
  console.log("Minting...");
  const mintTx = await basicNft.mintNft();
  const mintTxReceipt = await mintTx.wait(1);
  const tokenId = mintTxReceipt.events[0].args.tokenId;
  console.log(`Token ID: ${tokenId}`);
  console.log(`NFT Address: ${basicNft.address}`);

  if (network.config.chainId == 31337) {
    await moveBlocks(1, (sleepAmount = 1000));
  }

  let slot = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    slot = await ethers.provider.getStorageAt(basicNft.address, i);
    console.log(`Slot${i} : ${slot}`);
  }
}

mint()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

It's print slots like this:

```
Slot0 : 0x446f67696500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
Slot1 : 0x444f470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
Slot2 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Slot3 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Slot4 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Slot5 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Slot6 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
Slot7 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Slot0 is Dogie slot1 is DOG. So it's name and symbol of nft. We have some 0 slots. But how this works? Why is this like that? Why is not slot0 s_tokenCounter ?

Also I deployed contact on rinkeby: 0x3226ED61DE678f0c09B6A5919C0E5c67D0C09f95
BasicNft contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract BasicNft is ERC721 {
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter = 0;

    event DogMinted(uint256 indexed tokenId);

    string public constant TOKEN_URI =
        "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json";

    constructor() ERC721("Dogie", "DOG") {
        s_tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function mintNft() public returns (uint256) {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
        emit DogMinted(s_tokenCounter);
        s_tokenCounter++;
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );
        return TOKEN_URI;
    }

    function getTokenCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the token name and symbol state variables from the inherited OZ ERC721 contract taking precedence over the state variables in the child contract

```
i.e. 

// Token name
string private _name;

// Token symbol
string private _symbol;
```

which you've set in the constructor

Comment: So child contract take first spot? What if I have more than one child contract? Why the slots 2,3,4,5 is 0 ?

Comment: the parent is the one taking the first two slots. Inheritance goes from right to left. The default value of all slots is 0 as there is no concept of null in Solidity. The only other state variable you have in the contracts is `s_tokenCounter`, which is slot3 and is set to 0 (the default value)

Comment: But I already mint  nfts. So s_tokenCounter already 6. Which is that slot6. You can check on rinkeby contract. I just minted another one slot6 is now 7

Comment: On OZ er721 contract we have 4 mappings under the name and symbol. How mappings take space on storage?

Comment: yep. mappings are a special case I guess you could say. I had thought you'd ask about the declared constant next .I suggest this video to explain better than I can. https://m.youtube.com./watch?v=Gg6nt3YW74o